# What is this AES SBOX triplet property?

Tags: aes, collision-resistance, s-boxes

While playing around with the AES SBOX, I found out that there are 85 unordered triplets `(a, b, c)` that have the following characteristics:

- `a ^ b ^ c = 0`
- `SBOX[a] ^ SBOX[b] ^ SBOX[c] = SBOX[0]`

Furthermore, the `85*3 = 255` values from the triplets cover the `[1, 255]` range, which is cute as zero was singled out on the other side of the equation.

Here is some `python` code that demonstrates this property:

```
SBOX = [
        99, 124, 119, 123, 242, 107, 111, 197,  48,   1, 103,  43, 254,
       215, 171, 118, 202, 130, 201, 125, 250,  89,  71, 240, 173, 212,
       162, 175, 156, 164, 114, 192, 183, 253, 147,  38,  54,  63, 247,
       204,  52, 165, 229, 241, 113, 216,  49,  21,   4, 199,  35, 195,
        24, 150,   5, 154,   7,  18, 128, 226, 235,  39, 178, 117,   9,
       131,  44,  26,  27, 110,  90, 160,  82,  59, 214, 179,  41, 227,
        47, 132,  83, 209,   0, 237,  32, 252, 177,  91, 106, 203, 190,
        57,  74,  76,  88, 207, 208, 239, 170, 251,  67,  77,  51, 133,
        69, 249,   2, 127,  80,  60, 159, 168,  81, 163,  64, 143, 146,
       157,  56, 245, 188, 182, 218,  33,  16, 255, 243, 210, 205,  12,
        19, 236,  95, 151,  68,  23, 196, 167, 126,  61, 100,  93,  25,
       115,  96, 129,  79, 220,  34,  42, 144, 136,  70, 238, 184,  20,
       222,  94,  11, 219, 224,  50,  58,  10,  73,   6,  36,  92, 194,
       211, 172,  98, 145, 149, 228, 121, 231, 200,  55, 109, 141, 213,
        78, 169, 108,  86, 244, 234, 101, 122, 174,   8, 186, 120,  37,
        46,  28, 166, 180, 198, 232, 221, 116,  31,  75, 189, 139, 138,
       112,  62, 181, 102,  72,   3, 246,  14,  97,  53,  87, 185, 134,
       193,  29, 158, 225, 248, 152,  17, 105, 217, 142, 148, 155,  30,
       135, 233, 206,  85,  40, 223, 140, 161, 137,  13, 191, 230,  66,
       104,  65, 153,  45,  15, 176,  84, 187,  22
       ]

triplets = [(0x01, 0xBC, 0xBD),
            (0x02, 0x61, 0x63),
            (0x03, 0xDC, 0xDF),
            (0x04, 0xC2, 0xC6),
            (0x05, 0x7A, 0x7F),
            (0x06, 0xA3, 0xA5),
            (0x07, 0x19, 0x1E),
            (0x08, 0x97, 0x9F),
            (0x09, 0x22, 0x2B),
            (0x0A, 0xF4, 0xFE),
            (0x0B, 0x43, 0x48),
            (0x0C, 0x51, 0x5D),
            (0x0D, 0xE0, 0xED),
            (0x0E, 0x32, 0x3C),
            (0x0F, 0x81, 0x8E),
            (0x10, 0x25, 0x35),
            (0x11, 0x89, 0x98),
            (0x12, 0x44, 0x56),
            (0x13, 0xEA, 0xF9),
            (0x14, 0xE7, 0xF3),
            (0x15, 0x4F, 0x5A),
            (0x16, 0x86, 0x90),
            (0x17, 0x2C, 0x3B),
            (0x18, 0xA2, 0xBA),
            (0x1A, 0xC1, 0xDB),
            (0x1B, 0x66, 0x7D),
            (0x1C, 0x64, 0x78),
            (0x1D, 0xC5, 0xD8),
            (0x1F, 0xA4, 0xBB),
            (0x20, 0x4A, 0x6A),
            (0x21, 0xD6, 0xF7),
            (0x23, 0x96, 0xB5),
            (0x24, 0x88, 0xAC),
            (0x26, 0xCF, 0xE9),
            (0x27, 0x54, 0x73),
            (0x28, 0xD5, 0xFD),
            (0x29, 0x41, 0x68),
            (0x2A, 0x9E, 0xB4),
            (0x2D, 0x87, 0xAA),
            (0x2E, 0x58, 0x76),
            (0x2F, 0xCB, 0xE4),
            (0x30, 0x5F, 0x6F),
            (0x31, 0xD2, 0xE3),
            (0x33, 0x80, 0xB3),
            (0x34, 0x99, 0xAD),
            (0x36, 0xCC, 0xFA),
            (0x37, 0x46, 0x71),
            (0x38, 0xC8, 0xF0),
            (0x39, 0x4D, 0x74),
            (0x3A, 0x91, 0xAB),
            (0x3D, 0x8F, 0xB2),
            (0x3E, 0x53, 0x6D),
            (0x3F, 0xD1, 0xEE),
            (0x40, 0x94, 0xD4),
            (0x42, 0xB7, 0xF5),
            (0x45, 0xAE, 0xEB),
            (0x47, 0x8A, 0xCD),
            (0x49, 0xB6, 0xFF),
            (0x4B, 0x9C, 0xD7),
            (0x4C, 0x85, 0xC9),
            (0x4E, 0xA8, 0xE6),
            (0x50, 0xB1, 0xE1),
            (0x52, 0x82, 0xD0),
            (0x55, 0x9B, 0xCE),
            (0x57, 0xAF, 0xF8),
            (0x59, 0x93, 0xCA),
            (0x5B, 0xA9, 0xF2),
            (0x5C, 0xB0, 0xEC),
            (0x5E, 0x8D, 0xD3),
            (0x60, 0xBE, 0xDE),
            (0x62, 0xBF, 0xDD),
            (0x65, 0xA1, 0xC4),
            (0x67, 0xA7, 0xC0),
            (0x69, 0x95, 0xFC),
            (0x6B, 0x9D, 0xF6),
            (0x6C, 0x83, 0xEF),
            (0x6E, 0x8C, 0xE2),
            (0x70, 0x8B, 0xFB),
            (0x72, 0x9A, 0xE8),
            (0x75, 0x84, 0xF1),
            (0x77, 0x92, 0xE5),
            (0x79, 0xA0, 0xD9),
            (0x7B, 0xB8, 0xC3),
            (0x7C, 0xA6, 0xDA),
            (0x7E, 0xB9, 0xC7),
            ]

for t in triplets:
  print("%02X ^ %02X ^ %02X" % t, "= %02X" % (t[0] ^ t[1] ^ t[2]), " |  SB[%02X] ^ SB[%02X] ^ SB[%02X]" % t, "= %02X" % (SBOX[t[0]] ^ SBOX[t[1]] ^ SBOX[t[2]]))
```

I am looking for any kind of explanation as to where this is coming from. I am familiar with AES but couldn't relate these observations to anything I know about it.

Comment: Well, it seems "too nice" to just be a random property. I suspect there is some mathematical explanation behind which I am not aware of, I am looking for it.

Answer (score 10):

This is rather pretty if you understand finite fields and rather baffling if you don't. All the arithmetic takes place in $GF(256)$, so if you're not used to $1+1=0$, I apologise.

**Conversion to pure $GF(256)$ arithmetic**
Recall that the AES $S$-box can be written as $x\mapsto\ell(x^{254})$ where $x^{254}$ treats $x$ as an element of $GF(256)$ and $\ell$ is an invertible affine map. $x^{254}$ is some times termed the pseudo-inverse as for $x\neq 0$ we have $x^{254}=1/x$. By parity of operands, linearity and invertibility, we see that
$$\ell(x)+\ell(y)+\ell(z)=\ell(0)\iff x+y+z=0.$$
It follows that $(a,b,c)$ form a triple if and only if both of the equations
$$a+b+c=0$$
and
$$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=0$$
hold with $a$, $b$ and $c$ distinct and non-zero.

**Solving the simultaneous equations**
Our first equation will hold iff $a+b=c$ and so we have a solution if and only if
$$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1{a+b}=0$$
for distinct, non-zero $a$ and $b$. We multiply this equation by the non-zero quantity $ab(a+b)$ and see that we have a solution if and only
$$a^2+ab+b^2=0$$
for distinct non-zero $a$ and $b$. Dividing through by $b^2$ we see that we have a solution if and only if
$$\left(\frac ab\right)^2+\frac ab+1=0$$
which is true if and only if $a/b$ is a root of the equation $x^2+x+1$. This equation has two roots in $GF(256)$ as it is the defining polynomial of $GF(4)$ which is a subfield of $GF(256)$. In AES notation its roots are 0xBC and 0xBD (I'll write them as $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$).

**A recipe for triples**
We can now construct all of our triples. Let $a$ be any non-zero element of $GF(256)$ (accounting for the appearance of all value in our list). Let $b=\alpha a$ and let $c=(\alpha+1) a$. We now have
$$a+b+c=0$$
and
$$S(a)+S(b)+S(c)=0.$$
Giving us a triple. This gives 255 solutions, but we have over counted by a factor of 3 as the process will find each triple three times. QED.

Answer (score 1):

I ran some tests on random 8 bit permutation sboxes; I found (after running the count on 10,000 different random sboxes) that there were an average of 42.5 triples that meet the criteria (0 < a < b < c < 256, a^b^c=0, sbox[a]^sbox[b]^sbox[c]=sbox[0]).

Yes, there are a few more in the AES sbox; however not a huge amount...

Comment: 85 is twice the average of the random sbox case.

Comment: I would have expected a mean a little below 42.5 and standard deviation between 6 and 7 which would make 85 quite an outlier.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a differential uniformity viewpoint.

We are actually talking about *quadriples*, and these are actually contributing to the values $\ge4$ in the DDT (Difference Distribution Table) (recall that the AES S-Box as the 8-bit field inverse is differentially 4-uniform). For APN (Almost Perfect Nonlinear) functions (differentially 2-uniform), you will not find such quadriples *at all* (this is in fact, an equivalent characterization).

For example, from
$$S(x_1) \oplus S(x_1 \oplus \delta) = \Delta$$
$$S(x_2) \oplus S(x_2 \oplus \delta) = \Delta$$
You get a quadriple
$$S(x_1) \oplus S(x_1 \oplus \delta) \oplus S(x_2) \oplus S(x_2 \oplus \delta) = 0$$
Note that any 4 values $a,b,c,d$ such that $a\oplus b \oplus c \oplus d=0$ can be expressed in form $x_1,x_1\oplus \delta, x_2, x_2\oplus \delta$ (i.e., form a 2-dimensional affine subspace).

Given that $\{x_1, x_1 \oplus \delta\} \ne \{x_2, x_2 \oplus \delta\}$, we have a differential transition $\delta \leadsto \Delta$ having at least 4 satisfying input values $(x_1, x_1 \oplus \delta, x_2, x_2 \oplus \delta)$.

Comment: I believe your answer (which I will need some time to process because I do not know all these notions) is actually very much related to how I ended up observing what I asked. I was playing with collisions in the first MixColumns output. While exploring, I noticed that certain key byte pair values where yielding more collisions than others, having me wonder what these had special about them.

Comment: @slv white-box/side-channel collision attacks?

Comment: yes, indeed (stackexchange automatically retagged the question to "collision-resistance", not so appropriate as we are not in a hash context)